# How to use PowerShell to get all the computers in a sub-OU in Active Directory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get to:

```
Remote Sites
    MyCity
        Computers
```

and get a list of all the computers.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=MyCity,DC=MyDomain,DC=com" |
    Select -Property Name, DNSHostName, Enable, LastLogonDate
```

Comment: You forgot to ask your question. Does something about your code not work? What result did you get? How did it differ from the result you expected? Are you getting errors? What do they say?

Comment: Sorry, questions in the title, How do i use PS to list all computers in a sub-OU in Active directory. The code I have so far is giving me the Directory object not found error.

Comment: The distinguished name of the OU you want to search is probably `ou=Computers,ou=MyCity,ou=Remote Sites,dc=example,dc=com`, judging from the sample hierarchy you showed.